# Is there anyway to switch player 1 and player 2 gamepad in windows 10?

Tags: logitech-gamepad

I like to use the player 2 game pad because it's farther from the computer.

So I want the computer to think gamepad 2 is gamepad 1 and via versa.

How do I do so?

Comment: Take a look: https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/2qpugm/how_to_change_a_wired_xbox_360_controller_back_to

Comment: doesn't really work. Both controllers are connected by the same cable. I like player 2 because that means the cable is "longer". So there is a cable that connect player 1 to computer and then another cable that connect player 2 to player 1